# Linear stability analysis of PDE for porous media model

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading the article of Chuang et al. (2006), "The porous media model for the hydraulic system of a conifer tree: linking sap flux data to transpiration rate". 
They determine the follow PDE
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial \theta(x,t)}{\partial t}-\dfrac{1}{A(x)}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\rho g A(x) K(\theta)\right)-\dfrac{1}{A(x)}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[A(x) \dfrac{K(\theta)}{c(\theta)}\dfrac{\partial \theta(x,t)}{\partial x}\right]=0
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
c=\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial p}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
K=\dfrac{\tilde{k}}{A(x)}e^{-\left({-\frac{p}{d}}\right)^{c_2}}, \qquad \tilde{k}\;\; is \;\; a \;\; constant\, .
\end{equation}
They get that the stationary solution of this equation (i.e. for $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=0$) can be approximated - under proper hypothesis - as a constant value:
\begin{equation}
\theta_0(x,t)=1 .
\end{equation}
Then they turb the steady state solution by assuming
\begin{equation}
\theta(x,t)\simeq \theta_0(x,t)-\tilde{\theta}(x,t) \qquad where \qquad \tilde{\theta}(x,t)\ll \theta_0(x,t)
\end{equation}
and claim "using the approximation shown [$\theta_0=1$] to the linear order, $\tilde(x,t)$ satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial \tilde{\theta}(x,t)}{\partial t}= \left(\dfrac{K}{c}\right)_{\theta=1} \dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{\theta}(x,t)}{\partial x^2} + \left(\dfrac{1}{A(x)}\dfrac{dA(x)}{dx}-\rho g \dfrac{c_2}{d}\left(\dfrac{p}{d}\right)^{c_2-1}\bigg|_{\theta=1}\right) \left(\dfrac{K}{c}\right)_{\theta=1}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{\theta}(x,t)}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
where $K$ and $c$ are both evaluated at $\theta=1$."

I've repeated calculations ten times but my result is different from the one of the authors! Can anyone do these calculations and tell me if the result is the same of the one of the authors or not? And if yes, I'd ask you also some details because it's making me crazy!